# Changing Redux store using input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I'm **really** new to React, Typescript and Redux, < a week using them.

What I need, is to store a "userName" on Redux's storage, in order to validate it against other values in the storage. My problem specifically is not being able to store the userName, mostly because all examples use class based components, while I'm using functional ones. Here's what I have as of now:

```js
//User input component

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import * as actions from "../../actions";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import { ApplicationStateInterface } from "../../combineReducers";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

interface channelCreatorInterface {
    open: boolean;
    hideChannelCreator?: any;
    handleFormChange?: any;
}

const mapStateToProps = (
    state: ApplicationStateInterface,
    ownProps: channelCreatorInterface
) => {
    return {
        ...ownProps,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
    hideChannelCreator() {
        dispatch(actions.hideChannelCreator());
    },
});

const ChannelCreator = (props: channelCreatorInterface) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog
                open={props.open}
                onClose={props.hideChannelCreator}
                aria-labelledby='form-dialog-title'>
                <DialogTitle id='form-dialog-title'>Create channel name</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        To create a channel name, please enter your desired name here. We
                        will check for availability.
                    </DialogContentText>
                    <TextField
                        autoFocus
                        margin='dense'
                        id='name'
                        label='Channel name'
                        type='username'
                        fullWidth
            onChange= {HERE IS THE EVENT I NEED TO CAPTURE}
                    />
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button color='primary' onClick={props.hideChannelCreator}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Box id='saveButton'>
                        <Button variant='contained' color='primary'>
                            Save
                        </Button>
                    </Box>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChannelCreator);
```

---

```js
//Form change action
import { makeActionCreator } from "../utility";
export const HANDLE_FORM_CHANGE = "HANDLE_FORM_CHANGE";
export const handleFormChange = makeActionCreator(
    HANDLE_FORM_CHANGE,
    "payload"
);
```

---

```js
//Reducer

import { constants } from "os";
import { Reducer } from "redux";
import {
    CREATE_CHANNEL,
    DISPLAY_CHANNEL_CREATOR,
    HIDE_CHANNEL_CREATOR,
    HANDLE_FORM_CHANGE,
} from "../actions";

export interface channelCreatorInterface {
    open: boolean;
    state: "idle" | "saving" | "correctly saved";
    channelName: "";
}

export const channelCreatorInitialState: channelCreatorInterface = {
    open: false,
    state: "idle",
    channelName: "",
};

export const channelCreatorReducer: Reducer<any, any> = (
    channelCreatorState: channelCreatorInterface = channelCreatorInitialState,
    action: { type: any; state: channelCreatorInterface }
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_CHANNEL:
            return {
                ...channelCreatorState,
                state: "saving",
            };
        case DISPLAY_CHANNEL_CREATOR:
            return {
                ...channelCreatorState,
                open: true,
            };
        case HIDE_CHANNEL_CREATOR:
            return {
                ...channelCreatorState,
                open: false,
            };
        case HANDLE_FORM_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...channelCreatorState,
                channelName: "",
            };
        default:
            return channelCreatorState;
    }
};
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's go to your question:

Your reducer would need to use a payload from your action:

```
        case HANDLE_FORM_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...channelCreatorState,
                channelName: action.payload,
            };
```

and in your component, you would then use an event handler to dispatch an action with that payload:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
    // ...
    setChannelName: (channelName: string) => dispatch({ type: HANDLE_FORM_CHANGE, payload: channelName })
});
// in your component:
                    <TextField
                        autoFocus
                        margin='dense'
                        id='name'
                        label='Channel name'
                        type='username'
                        fullWidth
            onChange={event => props.setChannelName(event.target.value)}
                    />
```

But please note, that this is a very outdated style of writing redux.
For one, we recommend using the react-redux hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch`, which can replace `connect` in function components. Also, we recommend using [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) instead of writing plain redux reducers by hand, as that will save you a lot of code and also help a *lot* with the typescript typings.

If you are looking for an up-to-date tutorial, the official [Essentials Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) is the best place to start.

Also, if you have any quick questions that don't make good material for a stackoverflow questions, be sure to visit us over in the official redux channel on the reactiflux discord server.

Comment: Thank you SO much for the answer and insight! Will definitely check the tutorial and visit the Discord server for questions like this. Thank you once more!

Comment: To add to this answer, I would recommend that you use the `onChange` handler to set a local state and dispatch a redux action from the Save button `onClick` event instead.

Comment: Have to agree with @LindaPaiste there - generally [it is advised against sending every single keystroke to the store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux), instead form state should live in local state and only move to global on submission. But on the other hand, only a single input probably won't hurt.